# Get the value from array in JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm receiving JSON that typically looks something like this:

```
[{
    "objectName": "UDO_Job",
    "primaryKey": "123456789",
    "UDO_JobPart": [{
        "length": "24.0",
        "width": "24.0",
        "qty": "12"
    }, {
        "length": "24.0",
        "width": "24.0",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "length": "36.0",
        "width": "34.0",
        "qty": "3"
    }]
}]
```

I need to retrieve the `primaryKey` value, then the contents of each element of the `UDO_JobPart` array (`length`, `width`, and `qty`).

I am able to get the `primaryKey` value with this code:

```cs
var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
int primaryKey = jArray[0]["primaryKey"].Value<int>();
```

But I'm hitting a wall with getting the contents of the array. I tried something like this:

```cs
double length = jArray[0]["UDO_JobPart"][0].["length"].Value<double>();
```

But I'm not getting anything back. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating proper mdel classes and deserializing is no option for you?

Comment: If you have advice for a better approach than what I have attempted above, you are welcome to post it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.` between `[0]` and `[length]`.

```cs
double length = jArray[0]["UDO_JobPart"][0]["length"].Value<double>();
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/diqPqt)

---

Split from 1 line code above, the structure is as (for better understanding):

```cs
var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
var jObj = jArray[0];
var jobPart = jObj["UDO_JobPart"][0];
double length = jobPart["length"].Value<double>();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PHLv79)